# How do I make sure grunt only selects files (not folders)?

Tags: gruntjs, grunt-contrib-concat

I'm trying to concatenate all the JS libraries in our project into a single file. So I've set up a `concat` task in grunt, with the following file selector:

```
dist : {
  src  : ["public/lib/**/*.js"],
  dest : "public/lib.concat.js"
}
```

So far so good. However, we use [sprintf.js](https://github.com/alexei/sprintf.js) in our project. So there is a `sprintf.js` directory inside of `public/lib` and that directory is matched by the `src` selector in grunt.

The result of that is:

```
$ grunt
Running "concat:dist" (concat) task
Warning: Unable to read "public/lib/sprintf.js" file (Error code: UNKNOWN). Use --force to continue.
```

I'm aware that I could simply pick a different name for the `sprintf.js` directory, but I would like to know if there is a way to tell grunt to only select actual files, not directories.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [filter option](http://gruntjs.com/configuring-tasks#custom-filter-function) to ignore directories:

```
dist : {
  src  : ["public/lib/**/*.js"],
  dest : "public/lib.concat.js",
  filter: function(filepath) {
    return !grunt.file.isDir(filepath);
  }
}
```

Comment: I *do* want to match subdirectories. I just want it to read the file inside the directory `sprintf.js`. But grunt tries to read the directory as if it was a file.

Answer (score 0):

it should be even easier. you can just exclude with an exclamation pointer:

```
dist : {
  src  : ["public/lib/**/*.js", "!public/lib/sprintf.js" ],
  dest : "public/lib.concat.js"
}
```